# It's okay to define an object's property value relatively to its sibling?

Tags: reactjs, coding-style

For example:

```
state={ 
    viewIndex:0,
    travelerIndex: 100,
    viewValue: (this.stateviewIndex * this.state.travelerIndex)
  }
```

Here we can see that viewValue is defined relatively to viewIndex and travelerIndex. It seems a few recursive to me and I wonder if it's okay to do the thing like that.

Any hint would be great,
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a local function that computes the total value from the state instead of adding a layer of complexity into the state. I've created an example below. You can use the return value to do whatever.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    tomsWallet: 50,
    hannahsPurse: 49,
  }
  getTotalBalance = () => {
    return (this.state.tomsWallet + this.state.hannahsPurse).toFixed(2);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>Total Balance: £{this.getTotalBalance()}</div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Agree a function that computes the variable is the better option. It would also help working with dependable code, the way things are done in the question may create some state issues later & it will be difficult to spot.

Comment: thanks, and what mean the "£" in your code? Your would mean "$" maybe?